# React typescript add custom property to all React/Html elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to introduce a new custom property to all HTML elements, I get the below

```
index.js:1350 Warning: Unknown event handler property `onTap`. It will be ignored
```

I have created a index.d.ts file and added

```
import "react";
import React from "react";

declare module 'react' {
    export interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
        onTap?: (e: React.PointerEvent) => any;
    }
}
```

Is there anything else required?

Thanks

Comment: I think the proper way to do it is `extend` an existing `HTMLElement`. (`class MyElement extends HTMLElement`). Then you can add your custom properties there. That also removes the need for creating a `.d.ts` file. I've only tried this in vanilla JS though, not sure what happens in React :)

Comment: Hi. I used the pattern that I saw in other threads basically, but for some reason it is not working. Extending each html element I need the prop on is not ideal, since there can be many that will be using it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue I had was due to the new JSX transformation introduced in react 17
https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html
I was overriding React.createElement to intercept and apply logic on my custom props. The error I posted was thrown because the new JSX transformation bypass React.createElement in various situations, leading to the custom prop being passed to the HTML element.

Anyone wishing to disable the new transformation can use the below
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9873